# SQL WHERE clause not filtering out null column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't understand why I'm getting certain results when I run a SQL query. This is the query:

```
SELECT A.flag, B.type, B.aID
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.aID = A.aID
WHERE A.startDate = '2013-01-07'
    AND (A.flag = 1 OR B.type IS NOT NULL)
```

aID is the primary key on table A.

This is the result I get:

```
flag type aID
---- ---- ----
0    NULL NULL
```

I would have expected there to be no results. I am confused because A.flag is not 1 and B.type is null, which seems contrary to my WHERE clause. Note that there was no match for this row on table B, since B.aID is null in the result. When I run the query with only one of `A.flag = 1` and `B.type IS NOT NULL` instead of both, no results are returned instead of one result.

Curiously, when I replace B.type in the SELECT statement with ISNULL(B.type, 'X'), no results are returned. The same happens when I add `AND B.type IS NOT NULL` to the LEFT JOIN.

Why am I getting this result?

**Edit: Sample data**

Here is a query that gets rows from table A using two different start dates:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE A.startDate IN ('2013-01-07', '2012-11-23')
```

I get the following results (leaving out 6 columns for clarity):

```
aID     cID  sID  psID startDate               flag 
------- ---- ---- ---- ----------------------- -----
23844   75   72   86   2013-01-07 00:00:00     0    
23940   75   72   86   2012-11-23 00:00:00     1    
21061   76   73   87   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
21293   76   74   88   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
21477   77   75   89   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
21711   78   76   90   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
21944   79   77   91   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
22176   80   78   92   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
22410   81   79   93   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
22643   82   80   94   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
23344   83   81   95   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
22876   84   82   96   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
23639   85   83   97   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    
23109   89   84   98   2012-11-23 00:00:00     0    

(14 row(s) affected)
```

Using the aID that we found for 2013-01-07, we can see from this next query that there is no entry in table B that corresponds to that start date.

```
SELECT * FROM B
WHERE B.aID = 23844
```

This returns no results.

Using the aID's that we found for 2012-11-23, we can see that all but one of these have a corresponding entry in table B.

```
SELECT * FROM B
WHERE B.aID IN (23940,
    21061,
    21293,
    21477,
    21711,
    21944,
    22176,
    22410,
    22643,
    23344,
    22876,
    23639,
    23109)
```

Results:

```
bID   aID    type  duration iMinutes
----- ------ ----- -------- ---------
5836  21061  M     0        0
5893  21293  M     0        0
5916  21477  M     0        0
5975  21711  M     0        0
6033  21944  M     0        0
6092  22176  M     0        0
6150  22410  M     0        0
6208  22643  M     0        0
6266  22876  M     0        0
6530  23109  M     0        0
6382  23344  M     0        0
6478  23639  M     0        0

(12 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Is that really the query that gives you those results? Seems impossible...

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns `flag` and `type`?. I mean, are you sure that the value for `type` is not a text `'NULL'` instead of just `NULL`?

Comment: If your query is as you state it, and the queries with single clauses return nothing, then the only possibility that I can think of is that the one or both of the tables is being updated between the queries.

Comment: For fast and qualitative answer you can just create scheme with test data on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: Added sample data. This shows that type is not a text 'NULL' in my original results, since there is no row in table B that is being used.

Comment: As the other commenters say this should not be possible so (if this is repeatable and you can rule out concurrent modifications as the cause) either you've simplified something out of the query you have shown us or maybe you have some data corruption. Can you post the XML for the actual execution plans?

Comment: Or actually the output of `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON;` for both would do also.

Comment: Unfortunately, your "sample data" doesn't help - because you've given us some query results, not *sample data* that we could take and run on our own machines. You say "we can see", but at the moment, only *you* can see these things.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is happening because there are no service packs installed on this database (2008). Other databases with SP1 installed do not have this issue.

Comment: Could be nothing to do with it. If the issue is arising due to data corruption then you wouldn't expect the same issue to arise on other databases on other instances. I can't see "your" issue here [List of the bugs that are fixed in SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968369)

Answer (score -1):

It's because you are doing a LEFT (OUTER) JOIN. Perhaps an INNER JOIN is what you had in mind?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause runs on the result after the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and should exclude any rows left over that don't match `(A.flag = 1 OR B.type IS NOT NULL)`